# Controls added to placeholder in DetailsView nested in Gridview are not showing up

Tags: asp.net, gridview, nested, detailsview, dynamic-controls

I'm trying to add a TextBox and a RequiredFieldValidator to the InsertItemTemplate of a DetailsView nested in a GridView. I added a PlaceHolder in the InsertItemTemplate, and I'm doing the following in the GridView's OnRowDataBound event:

EDIT:  I realized I needed to add the ValidationGroup to the Insert LinkButton (lnkInsert), but this has no impact on the rendering of the TextBox and/or RequiredFieldValidator.  The ValidationGroup property also is not added to lnkInsert.  It seems like I cannot edit any controls inside the DetailsView in the RowDataBound event of the parent GridView.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    string valGroup = "PickListValidationGroup" + e.Row.RowIndex;

    // Add the validation summary
    PlaceHolder vsPlaceHolder = (PlaceHolder)e.Row.FindControl("ValidationSummaryPlaceHolder");
    ValidationSummary vs = new ValidationSummary();
    vs.ID = "PickListValidationSummary" + e.Row.RowIndex;
    vs.ValidationGroup = valGroup;
    vs.CssClass = "failurenotification";
    vsPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(vs);

    // Add the TextBox and RequiredFieldValidator
    DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)e.Row.FindControl("AddPickListOption");
    PlaceHolder displayPlaceHolder = (PlaceHolder)dv.FindControl("DisplayTextPlaceHolder");
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "txtDisplayText" + e.Row.RowIndex;
    tb.Text = "<%# Bind(\"DisplayText\") %>";
    RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
    rfv.ID = "DisplayTextRequired" + e.Row.RowIndex;
    rfv.ControlToValidate = tb.ID;
    rfv.ErrorMessage = "Enter text to display for the list option.";
    rfv.ValidationGroup = valGroup;
    rfv.ToolTip = "Enter text for the option";
    rfv.Text = "*";
    displayPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(tb);
    displayPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(rfv);

    // Add the ValidationGroup to the Insert LinkButton
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)dv.FindControl("lnkInsert");
    lnk.ValidationGroup = valGroup;
}
```

The ValidationSummary is added to the placeholder fine (it's not in the DetailsView), but the TextBox and RequiredFieldValidator are not showing up in the PlaceHolder in the DetailsView InsertItemTemplate.

EDIT:  Here is the DetailsView markup which is, again, nested in a GridView:

```
<div class="error_div">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ValidationSummaryPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
<asp:DetailsView ID="AddPickListOption" runat="server" Height="50px" 
    Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="PickListDataSource" 
    DefaultMode="Insert" EnableModelValidation="True" OnItemInserted="AddPickListOption_ItemInserted"
    OnItemInserting="AddPickListOption_ItemInserting" Visible="False" 
    OnItemCommand="AddPickListOption_ItemCommand">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Display Text:" SortExpression="DisplayText">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DisplayTextPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sort Order:" SortExpression="SortOrder">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPickListSortOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SortOrder") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price Change:" SortExpression="PriceChange">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPickListPriceChange" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PriceChange") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

What am I missing here?  I'm thinking this must be some kind of page/control life cycle issue that I don't have a solid understanding of yet.

Comment: You don't get any error messages?

Comment: Nope, all renders fine except the textbox in the detailsview. I can find the validation summary in the markup, but not the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just have a typo.  You create a TextBox variable named "tb" here, and set some attributes:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "txtDisplayText" + e.Row.RowIndex;
tb.Text = "<%# Bind(\"DisplayText\") %>";
```

Then you add a variable named "tb1" to the controls collection:

```
displayPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(tb1);
```

It's possible that "tb1" already exists elsewhere, which is why it doesn't really get added there.

Comment: I got excited, but unfortunately I only made the typo here. Still the same behavior. I'll edit the typos.

Comment: @user1405290 Is "Insert" your default mode?  If not, I wonder if it would help to add the TextBox and Validator OnModeChanged when changing to Insert mode.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional context, @user1405290.  Can you move this logic to the DataBound event of your DetailsView?  I'm conerned that it's somehow overwriting all or part of what you're doing because it's happening *after* the GridView's row has been databound.